# How can i get the information about current wallpaper in Android?

Tags: android, wallpaper

What I'm trying to know the file name or file size of current wallpaper.
I know how to get the drawable of current wallpaper like this:

```
ImageView view = new ImageView(this);
view.setImageDrawable(WallpaperManager.getInstance(this).getDrawable());
```

However, I can't find the way of getting more specified info.

I just want to set my server and make my server send one wallpaper per hour to some mobile device, and after some minutes, I want to check that the mobile's current wallpaper is what my server sent to it before.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortuantely, for static wallpapers there is no further information besides the information exposed by the `Drawable`. You need to store the `Bitmap` the server last sent to the device in your background service and then retireve the running wallpaper and compare the bitmaps manually. With API level 12 or bigger you can use the `Bitmap.sameAs` method, but before that you need to compare the pixels manually.

```
public static boolean equals(Bitmap bitmap1, Bitmap bitmap2)
{
    if (bitmap1 == null || bitmap2 == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 11)
    {
        return bitmap1.sameAs(bitmap2);
    }
    else
    {
        ByteBuffer buffer1 = ByteBuffer.allocate(bitmap1.getHeight() * bitmap1.getRowBytes());
        bitmap1.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer1);

        ByteBuffer buffer2 = ByteBuffer.allocate(bitmap2.getHeight() * bitmap2.getRowBytes());
        bitmap2.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer2);

        return Arrays.equals(buffer1.array(), buffer2.array());
    }
}
```